# How to load vue app.js from another location

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack

i'm stuck, i don't know how to solve this one, i hope someone has an idea:

i have two separate projects

- Vue frontend
- Laravel backend

both are running on my computer with different ports.

i want to keep those separate and have separate gits for each. each project should stay totally self-contained.

now i want to integrate a CSRF token into my index.html

the problem is: when i'm starting my builtin vue dev-server, the index.html is generated on the fly.
i thought i could just put `<script type=text/javascript src=http://localhost:8080/app.js> </script>` into laravel's index page and continue working as usual, but HMR doesn't work that way. **HMR seems to expect a connection from the same port where index.html is served from**

how can i have the index.html be served from lavavel, which contains the CSRF and load my app.js from another port on my machine (or ultimately, other URL in general)?

basic idea:

1. browse localhost:8080 (laravel)
2. get index.html with CSRF
3. then load app.js from localhost:8000

**important: i'm talking about the DEV build! i want to keep working on the project as if i was browsing to localhost:8000**

what is the right way to do this?

thank you very much for any help or pointer in the right direction

Comment: why it has to be done in  this way,  it's unnecessary to access Vue frontend page from Laravel backend.maybe you just want to get ajax data from your backend ,you can visit the frontend project directly,then the frontend makes a request to the backend through cors or jsonp

Comment: but how will i get the CSRF token that way? that has to be rendered into the index.html page by laravel, that's why i want to get index.html from laravel, app.js from my vue dev-build

Comment: HMR is designed to make code change  easily , the index.html generated by dev-server is  static, try to copy the CSRF token to vue project every time when the token is generated or refreshed

Comment: that's exactly what i'm trying to avoid :/

Comment: I wouldn't host the index.html through laravel. If you intend to host the frontend and backend on separate machines, they should be fully decoupled, so index.html belongs to the frontend.